# Al activar el certificado SSL mi pagina muestra una alerta de archivos faltantes

Tags: webservice, servidor, hosting, ssl, adobe-muse

Que tal espero me puedan ayudar, estoy trabajando con unos archivos de Muse que dejo otro diseñador pero penas hoy se hizo la activación de certificados SSL para los dominios de estos archivos, todo iba bien, hasta que hice el re direccionamiento, ahora amuestra una alerta que dice lo siguiente:

> Puede que determinados archivos falten en el servidor o sean incorrectos. Limpie la cache del navegador e inténtelo de nuevo. Si el problema persiste, póngase en contacto con el administrador del sitio web.

Obviamente ya limpie el caché, revise desde diferentes navegadores y computadoras, el asunto esta en que cuando accedo al sitio sin re direccionamiento osea **`http://www.misitio.com`** todo se ve bien, al poner **`https://`** es cuando lanza la alerta.

Comment: No nos das mucha información que de archivos estan bloqueados, podrias intentar ver cuales son utilizando el inspector de Chrome en su pestaña de Network, me suena que es un error al intentar obtener archivos que se encuentran en una dirección `http://` ya que no puedes hacer llamadas a recursos no protegidos `http` cuando tu sitio usa `https://`, mas info [aqui](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Security/Mixed_content/How_to_fix_website_with_mixed_content)

Comment: @Moz Gracias, por ahí iba el problema, basto con cambiar los permisos de la carpeta donde estaban los scripts de el sitio

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Este error se soluciona modificando las dependencias de archivos externos para que se hagan mediante HTTPS:// en vez de HTTP:// ya que al tener SSL instalando se requiere que la información llegue a la página y salga encriptada.